# K-D tree for ray tracing in a rotating scene

Tags: algorithm, graphics, raytracing

If I want to ray trace a scene using a K-D tree, and this scene happens to rotate every certain time, is it necessary to rebuild the K-D tree for each rotation or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

The better answer is no, not if you rotate your view matrix instead of the scene.  You should translate your camera (rays) into the scene, not the other way around.

Comment: Just to clarify, If the scene is changed by rigid body transformations (rotation, scaling, translation) you can still use your kd-tree, by transforming the ray with the inverse of the transform matrix.

Comment: thanks both of you guys. I know some of the theory around ray tracing and k-d trees, but now that I'm trying to give it a shot in C it's kinda difficult. =)